# Indicator LED on Optocoupler Circuit

Tags: led, opto-isolator

I want to add an indicator LED to an optocoupler circuit I made so I can have visual feedback for when the opto is being triggered.

Originally I hade wired the LED in series with pin 1 of the opto, but I was worried about being able to source enough current to satisfy the opto (target If ~25mA, max If ~50mA) while not damaging the indicator LED (Max current rating ~30mA).

As you can see in the below schematic, I decided to wire the LED in parallel with the opto, so I can easily control the current through both the opto (target is ~25mA) and the indicator LED (target is ~5mA).

Is that the best way to do it, or did I mess up somewhere?

The Arduino GPIO that I am using to drive the opto has a current sourcing capacity of ~40mA.

Vf of LED is 2V

Vf of opto is 1.2V

[image]

Comment: Why is the opto target 25mA? Thats 2 to 5 times more that usually. Which Arduino is this and which pin, which LED? You don't need to drive things at right below their absolute maximum ratings.

Comment: ‘Best way’? I can say it is a common way to solve the problem. I would question the need to run 25mA into the opto. 30mA on an Arduino pin is a bit high methinks. Especially if you have a number of optos to drive. Generally, I’d look at using a bjt/mosfet/ic to buffer the gpio for loads over, say, 3mA. If you have the micro switch significant currents, you get voltage drops across the bond wires in the package and can cause adc errors. This might not be an issue for your application, but it is something worth considering.

Comment: RGB, I pretty much agree with @Kartman comment. You don't want a single I/O pin at its max limit. There usually are port limits, as well, and this would almost certainly hog up the entire port limit, meaning you have not much left over for any other I/O pins sharing that IC region. You want to keep the drive currents relatively modest, unless there is a darned good reason otherwise. And an LED indicator doesn't often qualify (my book.) The CTR can be as bad as 50% I see. We know nothing of the collector current you need. So we are stuck on what to recommend for the opto LED, sadly.

Comment: Okay, I will reduce the Opto current to 10mA. In this case, all the arduino is doing is sending a pulse wave signal. The collector current I need is approximately 2.4mA.

Comment: Attach a transistor as a switch, if this is the only circuit. If there are many such circuits, use a buffer chip to take the load off the arduino pin.